# Web app server side encryption scheme

Tags: symmetric

I'm asking if this encryption scheme would increase the security of the user's data. Here's how it would work:

1. The user would create an account (username + password). An encryption key (symmetric) is created for the user, which is then encrypted with the user's password and stored into the site's database.
2. The encryption key is stored into the session cookie (because it is needed soon).
3. When the user enters some private data, the data goes to the server and is encrypted there with the key which is in the session cookie, and then stored into the database.
4. When the user reads some private data from the database, the data is decrypted with the key which is in the session cookie and sent to the browser.

So, in summary, when the user is logged in, the data is encrypted/decrypted at the server side, with the key, which is stored in plain text form in a session cookie. When the user is not logged in, the key is stored in the database in an encrypted form.

Does this make the user's data more secure than without this scheme?